# Change CSV headers while processing papaparse

Tags: javascript, parsing, papaparse

Is it possible to change the headers of a "csv" file to uppercase during the process performed by papa.parse using JavaScript?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

```
beforeFirstChunk: function(chunk) {
                    var rows = chunk.split( /\r\n|\r|\n/ );
                    var headings = rows[0].toUpperCase();
                    rows[0] = headings;
                    return rows.join("\r\n");
                },
```

supporting 'beforeFirstChunk' solved me this issue, nevertheless if you use 'worker: true' inside your configuration it will trigger an exception, looks like a known bug.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 5.0, PapaParse now has `transformHeader`, which is

> A function to apply on each header. Requires header to be true. The function receives the header as its first argument.
>   Only available starting with version 5.0.

You can see an example at [Using PapaParse transformHeader to remove whitespace from headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470745/using-papaparse-transformheader-to-remove-whitespace-from-headers).