# Using PapaParse transformHeader to remove whitespace from headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, papaparse

If we have a CSV file like this:

```
`firstName, lastName
 Jim, Carrey
 Stephen, Colbert`
```

Papaparse will output the dynamically typed result like this:

```
       {firstName: 'Jim',
       ' lastName': '30000'}
```

In order to just get `{firstName: 'Jim', lastName...}` PapaParse 5.0.0 has a `transformHeaders` option, but there's no documentation on how to achieve this result yet.

Anyone have a `transformHeader` snippet that does this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This ended up doing the trick:

```
const config = {
  delimiter: ",",
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  transformHeader:function(h) {
    return h.trim();
  }
};
```

Comment: I used this syntax instead:
`transformHeader: ((header: string) => {
    return ...
}`

Comment: If you want to remove the space from something like `First Name` then you can use ```transformHeader:function(h) {
    return h.replace(/\s/g, '');
   }```

Comment: ```transformHeader: ((header: string) => header.trim())```